# Site Under Construction Magento2 Hosting With Nginx And Local Domain

Tags: magento2

1. Trying to host Magento2 with Nginx
2. Have completed all the requirements to install magento2
3. Installed via composer in /var/www/html/test.mgt.com
4. Created nginx virtual host
5. It is now redirecting me to http://my-pub-ip/setup
6. There is no button to install it via browser, so installing it via cli
7. After installation it shows me site under construction.

> upstream fastcgi_backend {
> server  unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
> }
>
> server {
>
> listen 80;
> server_name test.mgt.com;
> set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/test.mgt.com/;
> include /var/www/html/test.mgt.com/nginx.conf.sample;
> }

> bin/magento setup:install 
> --base-url=http://test.mgt.com 
> --db-host=localhost 
> --db-name=mgt 
> --db-user=magento 
> --db-password=magento 
> --backend-frontname=admin 
> --admin-firstname=admin 
> --admin-lastname=admin 
> --admin-email=admin@admin.com 
> --admin-user=admin 
> --admin-password=admin123 
> --language=en_US 
> --currency=USD 
> --timezone=America/Chicago 
> --use-rewrites=1 
> --search-engine=elasticsearch7 
> --elasticsearch-host=127.0.0.1 
> --elasticsearch-port=9200